# Recurrence Formula for Bitonic Sorter Runtime

Tags: algorithms, sorting, parallel-computing

A Bitonic sorter takes a bitonic sequence as an input and the output is a sorted list. I want to analyse Bitonic Sorter by knowing its depth/runtime. Can anyone give an idea on its recurreence formula? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.iti.fh-flensburg.de/lang/algorithmen/sortieren/bitonic/bitonicen.htm